# How compute the expression of electromagnetic tensor explicitly as given here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, field-theory, tensor-calculus

I am trying to understand how the second line arrives at the last line of this expression.

For $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu -\partial_\nu A_\mu$

And $F^{\mu\nu} = \partial^\mu A^\nu -\partial^\nu A^\mu$

$-\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} = -\frac{1}{4}(\partial_\mu A_\nu -\partial_\nu A_\mu)(\partial^\mu A^\nu -\partial^\nu A^\mu$)

$-\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} = -\frac{1}{4}(\partial_\mu A_\nu\partial^\mu A^\nu -\partial_\mu A_\nu\partial^\nu A^\mu -\partial_\nu A_\mu\partial^\mu A^\nu + \partial_\nu A_\mu\partial^\nu A^\mu)$

$-\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu A_\nu\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial_\mu A_\nu\partial^\nu A^\mu)$

I am struggling to understand how does the second last line arrived at the last line. Can we just swap the indices of the third and fourth term on the right hand side, whilst locking the index swap on the first and second term ?

I appreciate if someone could kindly explain.

Comment: Do you know the component form of the Field tensor $F$ and of the 4-potential $A$ In terms of the electric and magnetic field? Are you familiar with the summation convention?

Comment: In the second line, the terms with the same sign are identical by taking $\mu \leftrightarrow \nu$.

Comment: @QuantumFieldMedalist How is it so ? So you are saying $\partial_\nu A_\mu \partial^\nu A^\mu $ is the same as $\partial_\mu A_\nu \partial^\mu A^\nu $ ?

Comment: As @QuantumFieldMedalist pointed out
$$\partial_\nu A_\mu \partial^\nu A^\mu =\partial_\sigma A_\rho \partial^\sigma A^\rho=\partial_\mu A_\nu \partial^\mu A^\nu$$
and similarly for the other pair.

Comment: Yes: each index is summed over ("summation convention") so you can rename them as long as you do so consistently. You might want to expand each sum by hand: each sum has sixteen terms and you should be able to see in short order that they are the same.

Comment: There is no need to expand each sum. Follow @QuantumFieldMedalist's instruction. This has no strict relation to electromagnetics. It's mathematics, enjoy the gift of Einstein's summation convention.

Comment: Imagine how many summation symbols $\Sigma_\mu\Sigma_\nu$ would be necessary in a contemporary physics textbook without Einstein's summation convention.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful comments, I think I finally understood this now. I was under the impression that $\mu\neq\nu$ is imposed here. But come to think that this can be expressed as $$\sum_{\mu=0} \sum_{\nu=0}$$ right? Thanks and cheers!

Comment: To have limits under and over the summation symbol $\Sigma$ or the integral one $\int$ use in MathJax `\limits` that is `\sum\limits_{\mu=0}^{\mu=3}, \int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}` as below
$$\sum\limits_{\mu=0}^{\mu=3} \qquad \int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta} $$

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Frobenius  $\sum\limits_{\mu=0}^{\mu=3} \limits\sum\limits_{\nu=0}^{\nu=3}$

Comment: Welcome to PSE, Han.